# Why Is MySQL Bridge Table Not Working?

Tags: mysql, create-table, bridge, mysqladmin

I currently have the following tables:  `Category`, `Product`, `Payment`, `User`.

The following is MySQL script for bridge table:

```
CREATE TABLE Order
(
  FOREIGN KEY UID MEDIUMINT REFERENCES User (UID),
  FOREIGN KEY PID MEDIUMINT REFERENCES Product(PID),
  FOREIGN KEY PayID REFERENCES Payment(PayID),
  PRIMARY KEY (UID,PID)
)
```

I am getting the following error in MySql:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'Order (
  FOREIGN KEY UID MEDIUMINT REFERENCES User (UID),
  FOREIGN KEY PID MEDI' at line 1
```

Please note that this is the last table.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @StrawberryI added more clarity to the question.

Comment: @Robbert I added more clarity to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order is a reserved word.  You should either change it or you can escape the name with backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE `Order` ( .... )
```